# client.getLocation() missing context root

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jax-rs, tomcat8

I am developing a small customer REST service with jax-rs and got some trouble with the `response.getLocation()` method.

This is a snippet of the test-client I am using:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    try {
        System.out.println("*** Create a new Customer ***");

        String xml = "<customer>"
                + "<firstName>John</firstName>"
                + "<lastName>Doe</lastName>"
                + "<street>Far</street>"
                + "<city>Away</city>"
                + "<state>FR</state>"
                + "<zip>99999</zip>"
                + "<country>USA</country>"
                + "</customer>";

        Response response = client.target(
                "http://localhost:8080/jaxrs/customers").request().post(Entity.xml(xml));

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create");


        String location = response.getLocation().toString();
        System.out.println("Location: "+ location);
        response.close();

        System.out.println("*** GET Created Customer ***");
        String customer = client.target(location).request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println(customer);
```

I am using "jaxrs" as context root defined via Eclipse Mars. The Customer is being created, but obviously because I am using the absolute path at this point.

But when executing `response.getLocation()` the location set is `http://localhost:8080/customers/1`. I need `http://localhost:8080/jaxrs/customers/1` instead.

- What is the reason for the missing context root in `response.getLocation()`?
- Do I have to define the context root somewhere else?
- Shouldn't the `response.getLocation()` method return the context root as well?

I am working with Tomcat8 and the `org.glassfish.jersey` jars for the REST service

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sounds more like a server side problem than a client one. Can you show your server code where you are creating the header

Comment: thank you very much, I found the bug in the server code, the context root was missing in the response.